# R dataframe header problem with hidden carriage return / line break

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, line-breaks, carriage-return

Using read.xlsx I'm reading in a worksheet to a data frame. The header of the worksheets has some line breaks / carriage returns which are visible with the Excel sheet open but not so much from the data frame. I'd prefer to fix in R (vs in worksheet). These are causing issues when referencing headers with hidden line breaks.

```
myData <- read.xlsx("myFile.xlsx", sheet = "Sheet1")
```

There's a column called `Design Estimate` that I want to reference in a for loop to perform calculations but when I attempt to reference it with R Studio, when I type `myData[[p,Des` R suggested `Design Estimate` and when I hit tab, it forces a line break as seen below and the code won't run:

```
for (p in row.names(myData))
{
  x <- myData[[p,"Design
Estimate"]]
}
```

I've tried manually typing with \r or \n in lieu of the *next line* but nothing works. Ideally I'd like to REMOVE ALL line breaks in ALL headers of `myData` before I begin using it but I can't figure out a method to do that.

Cheers in advance

Comment: You could gsub them out : `names(myData) <- gsub("\n", "_", names(myData))`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried this but for some reason i still cannot reference the column header. When I type `myData$Des` R suggested `Design _Estimate`  but when I tab to take it, R puts the `_Estimate` on a new line and the code won't run

Comment: I just ran `names(myData) <- gsub("\n", "_", names(myData))` 
and then `names(myData) <- gsub("\r", "_", names(myData))` 
and this allows me to reference the columns. However, now they have two under scores.
I then ran this to fix: `names(myData) <- gsub("_", " ", names(myData))` and it seems to work. Long, but cool

Comment: Ah. Maybe you need `names(myData) <- gsub("[\r\n]{1,2}", "_", names(myData))`

Comment: @AllanCameron - that did it!